# How to interact with git via a client or a 3rd party tool

Tags: git, github

I am doing a research and I need to interact with git via a program I write not via terminal
to simplify I cant find some documentation or anything relates to how I can create my own client such as "GitHub desktop"

I just need something to point me to the right way

Comment: libgit2 sounds like it

Comment: Besides Command-line Git, there are several options like Libgit2, JGit, go-git, Dulwich. See https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-B%3A-Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-Libgit2 and the following pages.